# Is There A Difference In What Render Engine I Use For Exporting Edited Videos Or Frames To Videos?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

If I have an edited video and I want to export it would there be a difference in what render engine i have set it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of the render engine has no impact on the video export. Video rendering has nothing to do with the rendering of a 3D scene.